# Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected, trying to pass array to a sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have an array and a `displayArray` sub which I try to use. However, I get a

> Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected error

Main sub:

```
Dim someArray() As Double
someArray = getBinsArray(sumLossesColl)
displayArray (someArray)
```

`displayArray` sub:

```
Sub displayArray(someArray() As Double)
    Dim i As Long


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, UBound(someArray) - LBound(someArray))).value = someArray
    End With
End Sub
```

'getBinsArray' function:

```
Function getBinsArray(dataArray() As Double)
    Dim binsNumber As Long
    Dim binSize As Double

    binsNumber = Round(VBA.Sqr(UBound(dataArray) - LBound(dataArray)) + 0.5)
    MsgBox ("binsNumber: " & binsNumber)

    binSize = (getMaxValue(dataArray) - getMinValue(dataArray)) / (binsNumber - 1)

    Dim resultArray() As Double
    ReDim resultArray(1 To bindsNumber) As Double
    resultArray(1) = getMinValue(dataArray)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To binsNumber
        resultArray(i) = resultArray(i - 1) + binSize
    Next


    getBinsArray = resultArray
End Function
```

What is the reason behind this? The types are `Double`, everything seems fine. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Change to call to `displayArray` to one of the following two ways:

```
call displayArray (someArray)
displayArray someArray
```

So either use 'Call' and put the parameter(s) in brackets, or omit the brackets. There are endless discussions which version to use, but at the end it's a matter of taste.